# How to share page title, image etc by copying link to facebook profile textbox?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, facebook

i want to do this[image: want]

I have this code in my header:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="576081109113732">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SadWorld">
<meta property="og:description" content="ashdbashdbaskdjasb">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sadworld.net/userImage/brunobg.jpg77.jpg">
<meta property="og:title" content="sfdxgchvj.">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://sadworld.net/Hello.aspx?storyid=1">
```

Comment: FB will scrape the og `meta` tags from your site as long as you have them defined properly. You can use this [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test the tag values.

Comment: For some reason after i used the  Facebook Debugger it started working. Thanks @Goose :D

Comment: Your page may have been cached, it may take some time before it updates. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook caches this data pretty heavily. One way to clear that cache is to use their linter tool.

Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Enter the URL you wish to check. That will show you what Facebook sees when it scrapes your page and it will also clear any cached data Facebook currently has.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have that part right. Make sure you add this after the `body` tag in your code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=258515144314430";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Hey @bboysupaman it doensn't work it still uses the title and image from my index page.

Comment: It can take a few minutes to load it into your page, especially if you have already tested it with the old settings. Try running it through the Facebook debugger and it will reload the data. Then trying again. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Comment: What is the purpose of this script?

Comment: It is a necessary part of the Facebook Social Plugins framework. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

Comment: I dont think the OP wanted a share button, but rather just to be sure that the og values would be scraped properly upon copying a link to the site in their post.

Comment: You are correct, but at the bottom of the page I just linked to, there is the documentation on using the "Share" framework for Facebook without the "Share" button. So, I'd recommend checking that out too. =)

Comment: You don't need to include the JS SDK to get open graph header tags to work.

Comment: You don't need to include the JS SDK to simply share links.